# How to know whether <div id="target"> is shown or not with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I tried $.isshown() but there is not this function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$(elem).is(":visible");
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [`:visible`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible) selector:

```
if($('div#target:visible').length){
    alert('target is visible');
}
```

edit: use Quintin Robinson's solution, it's much clearer