# Finding a visible div that is not hidden Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so i have two div's which are hidden using jquery's `.hide();` onload

I have two function to `.show();` them

```
function showIncorrectChar()
{
  $("#csq-incorrect-characters").show();
}
function showMinChar()
{
  $("#csq-min-characters").show();
}
```

Using Jquery/Javascript i need to find whether one of those div's are visible if they are i want it to do nothing if they aren't i need to call it

```
hideResultsTableContainer(); 
showResultsTree();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know whether <div id="target"> is shown or not with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448714/how-to-know-whether-div-id-target-is-shown-or-not-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `:visible` selector.

```
if (!$("#csq-incorrect-characters").is(":visible") || !$("#csq-min-characters").is(":visible")) {
    // either element is not visible - run your functions:
    hideResultsTableContainer(); 
    showResultsTree();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
     if ( $('#myitem').is(':hidden')){
    // perform logic if the item is hidden

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if($('#divName').is(':visible')({ ... } to check if the div is visible or not

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("#csq-incorrect-characters:hidden")) { 
   hideResultsTableContainer();  
    showResultsTree();   
}
```

will call the functions if the element with an id `#csq-incorrect-characters` is hidden